# Python 3 only return the last item (multiple "get" BeautifulSoup) of dinamic URL

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

We have a code that "curl" with every word that is in txt file line, with BeautifulSoup, to a web page with a dynamic URL

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import codecs

    def word(line):
        sign=""
        page = requests.get("http://page.com/"+line+"/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        count=0
        for x in soup.find_all('tr'):
            sign+=soup.find_all('tr')[count].get_text()
            count +=1
        return sign

    def all():
        with codecs.open('test.txt',encoding='utf-8') as fin:
            for line in fin:            
                print(word(line))

    all()
```

The problem is that only return the last "curl" and not the other "curls"

Comment: `page = requests.get("http://pagina.com/"+word+"/")`

Is this your actual code? it doesn't make much sense. It concatenates a string and a function object. This code shouldn't even run.

Comment: srr that was a word mistake

Comment: @WorrenGilgamesh Change `print(word(line))` --> `print(word(line.rstrip()))`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ epic problem when u read lines \n\r hahah, ty

Comment: @WorrenGilgamesh Glad to help. :)